# Can i form an equation for the series 1,2,5,6,9...

Tags: sequences-and-series

How can I verify if a value belongs to the series (1,2,5,6,9,10....) — take two consecutive and skip two consecutive?

Comment: The two joined series are $4k+1,4k+2$.

Comment: A value can only belong to at most one of these two series.

Comment: The question in the title and in the body are different. To answer the question in the body, as user @abiessu said, one can use congruences mod $4$. To answer the question in the title, try $$x_k=2k-1-\mathbf 1_{k\ \text{even}}=2k-\tfrac12(3+(-1)^k)$$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### An Answer

$$a_k = \lceil\frac{n+1}{2}\rceil + 3\lceil\frac{n-2}{2}\rceil$$

### How to Obtain It

Note that for $n$ odd, $a_n = 4\frac{n+1}{2}-3$, and for $n$ even, $a_n = 4\frac{n}{2}-2$. Thus, we *could* formulate it as such:

$$a_k = \left\{
\begin{array}{ll}
      4\frac{k+1}{2}-3 & n \mathrm{\;odd} \\ 
4\frac{k}{2}-2 & n \mathrm{\;even} \\ 
\end{array} 
\right.$$

However, notice that the difference in terms alternates from $1$ to $3$. That is, with $a_1 = 1$, $a_{n+1} = a_n+1$ for $n$ odd and $a_{n+1} = a_n+3$ for $n$ even. Now, how many $3$'s will we have in this series? Well, if we make a table, we get

$$a_1 = 1$$
$$a_2 = 1 + 1$$
$$a_3 = 1 + 1 + 3$$
$$a_4 = 1 + 1 + 3 + 1$$
$$a_4 = 1 + 1 + 3 + 1 + 3$$

and the amount of threes in each term is:

$$a_1: 0$$
$$a_2: 0$$
$$a_3: 1$$
$$a_4: 1$$
$$a_5: 2$$

We can formulate the amount of threes in a term $a_k$ as $\lceil\frac{n-2}{2}\rceil$

Additionally, the amount of ones is:

$$a_1: 1$$
$$a_2: 2$$
$$a_3: 2$$
$$a_4: 3$$
$$a_5: 3$$

Similarly, the number of ones in $a_k$ can be formulated as $\lceil\frac{n+1}{2}\rceil$

Thus, we multiply the amount of ones by one, and the amount of threes by three, giving us

$$\boxed{a_k = \lceil\frac{n+1}{2}\rceil + 3\lceil\frac{n-2}{2}\rceil}$$

Answer (score 2):

The numbers in your series are exactly those expressible as $4k+j$ for some $k\geq0$ and some $j\in\{1,2\}$. With this in mind, the natural criterion to verify that some number $n$ is in your series is to check if
$$
n-1\equiv0\mod 4\,\,\,\,\,\,\text{ or }\,\,\,\,\,\,\,n-2\equiv1\mod4.
$$
Or, for a somewhat more compact way, to check if $\,\,(n-1)(n-2)\equiv0\mod4.$